# Mulitiple row insert in Sequel skip if unique constrain occurs Ruby sequel

Tags: sql, ruby, sequel

I know `Dataset#multi_insert` and `Dataset#insert`. does multi insert but is there an option available that can skip that particular insert when unique constrain check get activated

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`insert_conflict`](https://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-adapters/classes/Sequel/Postgres/DatasetMethods.html#method-i-insert_conflict) method.

> "Handle uniqueness violations when inserting, by updating the
> conflicting row, using ON CONFLICT. With no options, uses ON CONFLICT
> DO NOTHING."

```rb
DB[:table].insert_conflict.insert(a: 1, b: 2)
# INSERT INTO TABLE (a, b) VALUES (1, 2)
# ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
```

It also works with `multi_insert`

```rb
DB[:table].insert_conflict.multi_insert([{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}])
# INSERT INTO TABLE (a, b) VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4)
# ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
```